# How many disks does RAID One require?

Tags: raid

How many disks does RAID One require?

Answer (score 5):

A RAID 1 creates an exact copy (or mirror) of a set of data on two or more disks, so you need at least **2** disks. You can read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1) for more.

Comment: RAID 1 also requires an even amount of drives.  If you want to use an odd number (like 3 drives) you need RAID 1E.

Comment: I think it would be wasteful to use it with any more than two drives, as you lose half your storage space.  Using a parity level like RAID-5 would be better, or RAID10 (or RAID0+1), which gives you speed as well as mirroring.

Comment: while I'm sure it depends on the raid controller, you might use Raid1 with >2 disks (over Raid5/10/0+1) if you were worried about being able to access the data in the event that you lose the raid controller (ex: HW failure + no replacement)

Comment: So harddrives and two other hard drives?

Comment: Yes, one harddrive (source) and two other harddrives to be used for RAID 1.