# RAID 1 - speed with diferent speed disks

Tags: raid-1

I have a RAID 1 with an SSD and an HDD disk.

Of course the write speed should be the same as the HDD disk, but the read speed? The SSD disk is called more times than the HDD? Or RAID1 call exactly 50% of the content on each disk?

Comment: I'm betting that the technically correct answer is: it depends on the implementation.  Advanced implementations likely notice speed differences and adjust for optimal speed.  By the way, some info does indicate RAID 1 can potentially use more than 2 disks.  (See: [how many disks for RAID 1](http://superuser.com/questions/258831/how-many-disks-does-raid-one-require).)  So might not be precisely 50%.

Comment: well. Can I implement this with mdadm on linux?
I know, the 50% was just an expression